# Missing Dependencies When Running a CSharp Project on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I'm new to C#.
I have compiled a C# project on Linux (or rather: on WSL2, Ubuntu 22.04) like this:

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0
cd <project directory including csproj file>
dotnet build
```

When running it (`dotnet test`) I get the following error message:

> Test method Foo threw exception:
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Bar' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'dl' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [...]

How do I provide the missing dependency?
There is nothing broken with my Ubuntu setup. It's not like *libdl.so* is corrupted or anything.

Comment: Is there a reason you used `test`and not `dotnet run`?

Comment: It is a unit test, as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest.
There is no Main(). So `dotnet run` doesn't work.

Comment: I made it work by creating a symbolic link to my system's libdl and adjusting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
```
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 libdl; LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(pwd)"; dotnet test
```
I'm not happy with the solution and still would like to know what is going on.

Comment: From which apt repository did you get that dotnet-sdk-6.0 package, Microsoft's or Canonical's? In case you got it from Microsoft, did you follow [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup?pivots=os-linux-ubuntu#i-need-a-version-of-net-that-isnt-provided-by-my-linux-distribution) steps in addition to [registering the package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#register-the-microsoft-package-repository) from Microsoft?

Comment: `apt search dotnet-sdk-6.0` tells me _dotnet-sdk-6.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.0.123-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed]_.
jammy-security would be http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/